# Arranging array in a proper format

Tags: php, arrays

Hi friends this is my array:-

```
 [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => rel
                [value] => 8th 
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => imag
                [value] => media/fil
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => dur
                [value] => 130
            )

        [id] => 1009
    )
```

I want the output to be like this :-

```
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => rel
                [value] => 8th
                [id] => 1009
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => imag
                [value] => media/fil
                [id] => 1009
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [name] => dur
                [value] => 130
                [id] => 1009
             )

    )
```

Can anyone help me out ??

I tried most of the array functions but its not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$id = $array['id'];
unset($array['id']);
foreach($array as $k=>$v) {
    $array[$k]['id'] = $id;
}
```